# How to send a string as POST data from a different page?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a search page with an input box in my `index.php`. The form is using POST method.

```
<form id="someID" action="result.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Now I want to send a string to that input box from `result.php` page using a link like this-

`<a href="javascript:void(0)">Some Name</a>`

I can get the content of this link using JS and can send the name to result page if I use GET method.
**Example: `http://example.com/result.php?name=value`**

But I cannot use GET here.
Can I send the content of this link as a string to the result page using POST method? Any ideas?

Comment: you can just use post, and for getting a value while using `post` you would need to use `$_POST['value']` instead of `$_GET['value']` .. works pretty much the same, except that post is safer, and it doesnt get embedded in your url

Comment: Your question is unclear. If u click that link you want to go to result.php and make that the input with name is filled in?

Comment: @DarkBee yes, in this case, "Some Name" will be filled in to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (to make AJAX simpler than vanilla JS) it would look like this:

```
$.post('http://example.com/result.php', { name: value }, function(data) {
    // data -> returned HTTP request
});
```

Comment: Hi @chen-asraf, thanks for the help. I'm new to PHP and confused here with something. The `data` returned the whole page in html format when I run this code. How can I modify this so that the form of my home page will actually submit? Also this code only works in my home page, not in every pages.

Comment: returned response, not request

Answer (score 0):

U can do that with something like this, ajax here is not realy an option because you want to go to another page

## main

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="search">Foo</a>
    <a href="#" class="search">Bar</a>
    <a href="#" class="search">Foobar</a>
    <form id="just_a_form" action="result.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" value="" />
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.search').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#txt_name').val($(this).html());
                $('#just_a_form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['txt_name'])) {
            $name = $_POST['txt_name'];
        }else{
            $name = '';
        }
    ?>
    <form id="someID" action="result.php" method="post">
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```